# Python 3 is_alive call showing the wrong result

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.2

I am trying to use is_alive() to test one thread from another in Python 3.2.
If i use `thread1().is_alive()` in `thread2` i get `false` instead of `true` whether  `thread1` is running or not.

I get the same result if i put `thread1().is_alive()` inside `thread1` but if i put 
`self.is_alive()` inside `thread1` it returns `true` as expected.

It looked to me as if the command should be `thread1.is_alive()` but that says 1 argument required & fails.

I feel i am missing something simple but have been unable to find what that is.

A pointer would be appreciated, thanks

Ok thanks, test code looks like this:

```
import threading
import time
#
class FirstThread(threading.Thread):
    def run (self):
        while 1:
            print ('This is the First thread')
            print(self.is_alive())
            time.sleep(1)
FirstThread().start()
#
class TestThread (threading.Thread):
    def run ( self ):
        while 1:
            print ('This is the thread alive test thread')
            print(FirstThread().is_alive()) 
            time.sleep(1)
TestThread().start()
```

Comment: `thread1().is_alive()` implies that `thread1` is callable, strange. What's `type(thread1)`? Are you sure it's `threading.Thread`?

Comment: I'd love if you could post a minimal working code sample that reproduces your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginner mistake, the started "first" thread object is not referenced, and `FirstThread().is_alive()` tests an ephemeral object that is never started.